# Why WCF nettcpBinding is slow on local machine

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to check the WCF latency on my local machine. And it takes 2-4 millisecond/request (which seems to slow). I am not sending or receiving any complex object (so no serialization/deserialization involved).

Here is the service part:

```
    public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }
}
```

Here is the server's config.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="defaultNetTcpBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  <services>        
    <service name="WcfTestApplication.Service1">  
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/WcfTestApplication/Service1.svc" contract="WcfTestApplication.IService1" binding="netTcpBinding" />
      <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexTcpBinding"/>         
    </service>
  </services>
```

And here is the client code

```
            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost/WcfTestApplication/Service1.svc");
        ChannelFactory<IService1> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, address);
        IService1 _clientProxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {

            IService1 _clientProxy1 = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            var data = _clientProxy1.GetData(4);
            ((IClientChannel)_clientProxy1).Close();
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Updated:
Strange enough, there is no difference when I change binding to Named pipe. It still takes 2-4 millisecond/request.

Comment: Well you are opening and closing the channel for each request...

Comment: @CodeCaster - Perhaps, but OP is doing it via `ChannelFactory<T>`, so all they're really doing is getting a new channel and then closing that channel each time, which should be relatively fast, as opposed to creating a new client and closing that every time.

Comment: Opening and Closing channel (for every request) is a recommended practice. We should re-use channelFactory object. And I am re-using that.

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but when I was testing a WCF service in my local machine (client Windows version) the latency was ~30ms. Testing, however, in Windows Server, latency was < 1ms.

Comment: @andre_ss6, You mean, it was slower on client machine, but on server it very fast (almost 30 times)

Comment: Yes, when testing in a client Windows (both hosting the service and starting the client in the same machine), it was way slower. Testing in a Windows server machine, though, was faster. I even thought it could be IIS Express vs full IIS, but IIS Express was faster on Windows server nonetheless (and full IIS was slower as well in the client Windows).